# How do I retrieve a row with max/min column based on a condition from a set of grouped data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with the following structure and sample data:

```
id | date         | nutrient_number | nutrient_goal_value
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | "2019-01-01" | 1               | 5
2  | "2019-01-05" | 1               | 6
3  | "2019-01-06" | 1               | 7
4  | "2019-01-01" | 2               | 20
5  | "2019-01-05" | 2               | 25
6  | "2019-01-06" | 3               | 10
7  | "2019-01-10" | 3               | 8
```

I need to retrieve a single row per nutrient_number, so in this example I would need 3 rows to be returned. My thinking is I would group by nutrient_number.

```
SELECT * from nutrient_goal_table GROUP BY nutrient_number
```

But, the returned row needs to be the row with the **maximum date** *before or ==* the date I query with (if it exists), and if it doesn't exist then it should be the row with the **minimum date** *after* the date I'm querying with.

I could get this to work for one of the conditions, like so:

```
SELECT id, MAX(date), nutrient_number, nutrient_goal_value
FROM nutrient_goal_table
WHERE date <= '2019-01-06'
GROUP BY nutrient_number
```

This returns:

```
id | date         | nutrient_number | nutrient_goal_value
---------------------------------------------------------
3  | "2019-01-06" | 1               | 7
5  | "2019-01-05" | 2               | 25
6  | "2019-01-06" | 3               | 10
```

which is fine. However, if I had to do a query like the following:

```
SELECT id, MAX(date), nutrient_number, nutrient_goal_value
FROM nutrient_goal_table
WHERE date <= '2019-01-05'
GROUP BY nutrient_number
```

I would obviously only get 2 results, when I need there to be 3.

```
id | date         | nutrient_number | nutrient_goal_value
---------------------------------------------------------
2  | "2019-01-05" | 1               | 6
5  | "2019-01-05" | 2               | 25
```

To get the third result, I would need the above query to fetch the closest date past the date I supply i.e. the minimum date which is greater than the supplied date, but it should only do so if no rows exist that have a date <= the supplied date.

The result set I need would look like this with a supplied date of '2019-01-05'

```
id | date         | nutrient_number | nutrient_goal_value
---------------------------------------------------------
2  | "2019-01-05" | 1               | 6
5  | "2019-01-05" | 2               | 25
6  | "2019-01-06" | 3               | 10
```

I've been racking my brain for a while now, but I'm not very experienced and I'm struggling to come up with a solution. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `max(date)` or `min(date)` you can use `coalesce()` included in a join constraint:

```
select n.* 
from (SELECT distinct nutrient_number from nutrient_goal_table) d
inner join nutrient_goal_table n
on 
  n.nutrient_number = d.nutrient_number
  and 
  n.date = coalesce( 
    (select max(date) from nutrient_goal_table where date <= '2019-01-05' and nutrient_number = d.nutrient_number),
    (select min(date) from nutrient_goal_table where date >= '2019-01-05' and nutrient_number = d.nutrient_number)
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qdE4uvgCyUBLfWyZmMM8PP/0).